# Ips used by the same person?

Tags: ids

Is it possible to find out if ips are from the same location and used by one person. We have a situation were three ips have been logged etc. We know for sure that two are from the same person this xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx was the first in our data base.

These two xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxand xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx came after and are positively linked to one account. They are all xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and we have spoken to the guy concerned and he lives within a couple of miles from this location. The question is does the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ip belong to him also.

In our data base we only have three ips that start xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx no others are logged. How is it possible to find out if all three ips are linked to the same person..

Thanks for all your help 
Any help would on this and we would great.

Thanks

Denis

Comment: You can't exactly tie two separate IP addresses together with no other information other than they look similar. What type of services are they trying to use? Is this a web application? This cannot be done on layer3 unfortunately, but can easily be done on layer 7. So again, details will help.

Answer (score 6):

It's generally not possible to tie a person to specific IP addresses without corroborating information, or help from an ISP/the police.

The IP addresses you have listed all fall into a netblock owned by an Ottowa based company, which would tie in with what you've found so far.

Realistically if that's all the information you have you'd need to see if the ISP will help you (assuming they keep logs of which of their customers had what IP address and when).  Even then it's unlikely to tie to a specific person, just a subscriber account for the ISP in question.

So I'm afraid the short answer is no, in the general case you can't tie an specific IP address to a specific person.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other information, such as a cookie ID or session information, that might serve to demonstrate the same browser was used at multiple IP addresses.  But if you're just looking at raw network traffic, they won't help.

If it's a criminal matter, you could contact the ISP and request their DHCP logs for the dates and IP addresses in your trace files.  But at that point you better be ready to involve the police, meaning the crime would be something they'd have to take seriously. Many ISPs would be reluctant to confirm such information without a subpoena.